# LOGD statement in cpp file not showing up in Android Studio logcat

Tags: android, c++, android-source

I added logs in the camera 2 API client side c++ code. The file in the AOSP source code locates at the following path:

/frameworks/av/camera/camera2/ICameraDeviceUser.cpp

Here is how I added the log in the CPP file:

```
#define LOG_TAG "MY-DEBUG"
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
```

In the function of interest, I use the LOGD to print the name of the function as following:

```
    virtual status_t waitUntilIdle()
{
    ALOGV("waitUntilIdle");
    LOGD("waitUntilIdle");
    Parcel data, reply;
    data.writeInterfaceToken(ICameraDeviceUser::getInterfaceDescriptor());
    remote()->transact(WAIT_UNTIL_IDLE, data, &reply);
    reply.readExceptionCode();
    return reply.readInt32();
}
```

But the log is not showing up in the Android Studio logcat window. Could anyone help me out here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not use `ALOGD`?